# iPhone Localization Korean, Japanese Codes

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization

How do I find the localization codes for Korean, Japanese, German?

I want to localise my app in these languages.  Does it matter what code I use in Xcode?

When I add a new localizable.strings file?   There's an option "Add new Localisation".   Korean & Japanese are not listed.   Does Xcode need a specific localization code for it to work?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Japanese is "ja" not "jp"

I originally made this mistake as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this list helpful for finding country codes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Answer (score 0):

For German use: de

For Japanese use: jp

For Korean use: ko

You can create the ".lproj" folders manually and then add the files from those folders by dragging them to the resource group in XCode.